# Counting matching substrings in a string

Tags: python

```
s = "abobabobabob"
total = 0

for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i-1 : i+2] == 'bob':
        total += 1

print ('times bob occurs is:' + str(total))
```

Is there a simpler way to change the `if` statement? Also, could someone tell me what `i-1 : i+2` does?

I wrote this code to find the occurrences of "bob" and I am stuck for a while.

Comment: Please give your question a more useful title.

Comment: Your indentation is messed up. It's critical to get indentation right in Python.

Comment: See http://pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/ for an explanation of what `s[i-1 : i+2]` means. It's a string slice.

Comment: It's also wrong, it should be `s[i : i+3]`. And the loop should use `range(len(s)-2)` so it doesn't try to access outside the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code searches for the beginning index of each `'bob'` substring, and adds that value to an array. The `total` variable just returns the count of the values in that array.

**As a one-liner:**

```
total = 0
s = "abobabobabob"

total = len([i for i in range(len(s)) if s.find('bob', i) == i])

print('times bob occurs is: ' + str(total))
```

**Prints:**

```
times bob occurs is: 3
```

***--- Here is an alternative if you want a modification to your `for` loop:***

```
total = 0
s = "abobabobabob"

for i in range(len(s)):
    if (s.find('bob', i) == i):
        total += 1

print('times bob occurs is: ' + str(total))
```

**Prints:**

```
times bob occurs is: 3
```

Comment: Nice one-liner +1. But since he used a for loop, and had indention issues, might I suggest also showing him how to do this using a regular for-loop?

Comment: Added a for loop modification to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your if-statement is looking at a subset of s. To sort of answer your other question, here's a simpler approach that changes more than the if-statement:

This is python's regular expression library

```
import re
```

The embedded statement searches for all, non-overlapping instances of 'bob' and returns a list with each match as an element; the outer statement just counts the number of elements in the list

```
len(re.findall('bob',s))
```

Answer (score 1):

if s[i-1 : i+2] == 'bob' is checking whether the current index -1 to current index + 2 is 'bob'. It will cause issue, since i begin at 0 and i-1 is the last element of list

try:

```
s = "abobabobabob"
total = 0

for i in range(1,len(s)):
    if s[i-1 : i+2] == 'bob':
        total += 1
```

there is a better way in two line

```
s= "abobabobabob"
print sum(  s[i:i+3] =='bob' for i in range(len(s)-2) )

3
```

Comment: I tried OP's code and it didn't cause an error (after adding proper indentation). I was quite surprised.

Comment: @ChadDavis it should not. in python index can be negative. s[-1:2] is empty string

Comment: first tested it out in IPython, and then put the script in a file and executed it -- still worked. Using Python 3. This will be worth looking into.

Comment: @ChadDavis yes, it should not have issue at all. it is valid code

Answer (score 1):

Using `enumerate()`

```
s = "abobabobabob"
n = len([i for i, w in enumerate(s) if s[i:i+3] == "bob"])

print ('times bob occurs is:', n)
```

This checks for every character in string `s`(by index `i`) if the character + two characters on the right equals "bob".

---

About your secundary question:

In your example:

```
s[i-1 : i+2]
```

refers to the index (`i`) of the characters in the string, where `s[0]` is the first character, while `s[i-1 : i+2]` is a *slice* of the string `s`, from the current character `-1` (the one on the left) to the current character `+2` (the second character on the right).

Comment: _Using enumeraste()_ - Do you mean _enumerate_?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry `aste` ate `ate` :) Thanks for mentioning!